# AutoComplete : setting a float as the adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, autocomplete

So,i have 2 `AutoCompleteTextViews`.One has the product name and the second the product price.
What i want to do is this : when the user picks an option from the first ACTV dropdown,lets say he picks `Cheese`, i will get the price of `Cheese` from my sqlite database,turn it into an adapter and set that adapter for the second AutoCompleteTextView(it will only have one value,the price of the product name that was picked from the ACTV dropdown).I don't want to do .setText,if you're thinking about that.

I took care of getting the value from the DB,i already tested that by `.setText`,it works great,it's getting the value from the DB.
My issue is now with setting that value as the ACTV adapter.
This is what i've tried :

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String blabla=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            int blabla2=getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getId() ;
            int nextviewz=blabla2+2;
            AutoCompleteTextView ACpret=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(nextviewz);

            Float belea = sqlliteCountryAssistant.getEmployeeName(blabla);

            ArrayAdapter<Float> adapterz = new ArrayAdapter<Float>(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, belea);
            ACpret.setAdapter(adapterz);
        //  ACpret.setText(belea.toString());

        }
    });
```

I get `The constructor ArrayAdapter<Float>(MainActivity, int, Float) is undefined`.
I guess that's not the way to set a single value as an adapter,i tested and it works only with `String[] or Float[]`.
What do i need to do to make it take `Float belea` as adapter ?
Thanks in advance and have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Float[] belea= new Float[1];
belea[0] = sqlliteCountryAssistant.getEmployeeName(blabla);
ArrayAdapter<Float> adapterz = new ArrayAdapter<Float>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_item, belea);
```

does it work?

Comment: It surely does ! Thanks a lot and have a nice day !